# "No such file or directory" sp.Popen module

Tags: python, ffmpeg, popen

I am trying to take a video and convert it in audio , for this I am using ffmpeg in python. I run the following command but it gives me " No such file or directory" for the input file. Here's the code-

```
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"
import subprocess as sp
command = [FFMPEG_BIN, '-i', '/home/suryansh/Downloads/t.mp4']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE)
```

After executing this code I get `home/suryansh/Downloads/t.mp4: No such file or directory` but the file is their in the path specified.

Comment: Does the error omit the initial `/`? That might explain why the file is not being found

Comment: provide the full traceback. Are you sure `ffmpeg` is in `$PATH` in the environment where `python` script is executed?

Comment: Beware that it sometime throws this error `No such file or directory` when there is a problem of (I'm not talking about a problem with the path). Try another syntax

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
shell=True
```

after the "command", and i think that you could guide for the next example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312166/4941927

Comment: it doesn't help. with `shell=True` only ffmpeg will be executed

Comment: amm sorry dude i cant help you, I did what I could, sorry